# Crystal Reports: 4 pages, 1 report, 4 different headers

Tags: crystal-reports

I am having troubles creating CR report with multiple pages.

What I am trying to achieve is:
Page 1: report
Page 2: same report with different header
Page 3: still same report as page 1 with different header
Page 4: same analogy

Now my reports is designed for 1 page.

Any tips? I'm little frustrated ATM...

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need 4 Page Header sections.  Each section will use a formula to be suppressed based upon the page number of the report.  Each Page Header will be configured in the unique design needed for each of your 4 pages.

If you only have 1 row of data in your database that needs to generate all 4 reports, then you will also need 4 Details sections that use the same formula to be suppressed by page numbers.  The design of the details sections will all be identical.

At some point you will also want to set the "New Page After" check box on a section.  This can be done on each of the 4 details sections, or in the Page Footer sections if you use them.  If you use Page Footer sections, they will likely need to use the suppression formula by page number as well.

This setup will yield 4 pages of the same data on each page, with unique page headers.

The complexity of your suppression formula will vary depending upon how much data you plan to print with each run of the report.  If it will only be 1 report with a total of 4 pages then the formula will be rather simple since you only need to check for 4 possible values of `PageNumber`.  If you plan to print multiple reports in this manner per run, then you need to check for `PageNumber` values that are multiples of 4 + n, where n is either 1, 2, 3, or 4.  This still isn't an incredibly complex formula, providing you are 100% certain that none of the 4 pages needed for each row of data will ever exceed a single page.  If that happens, the complexity of the report becomes much greater.